# Suspected Chrome bug: CSS `last-of-type` not updating on webcomponent

Tags: css, google-chrome, web-component, native-web-component

**NOTE**
THe below question is flawed, please rather refer to:  [Suspected Chrome bug: CSS `last-of-type` not updating in webcomponent if apply certain styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530544/suspected-chrome-bug-css-last-of-type-not-updating-in-webcomponent-if-apply-c)

Below you will see a list of gray blocks, items `111` to `555`. 2 Seconds after running another item will be created via JS and appended to the list. The `NEW` item will be styled as `last-of-type`, but the previous `last-of-type` will remain styled as if was last-of-type, but it no longer is!

My current fix is when appending a new item to the list, hide the old last item (`555`) in this case, then show it again, this is done by setting `display: none` then `display: block`. Unfortunately it results in a flicker on more complex web components. Is there any way to make `last-of-type` update with a flicker? Am I using `last-of-type` incorrectly? Is it a Chrome bug?

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({mode:'open'});
    const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE");
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('wc-foo', Component);

setTimeout( () => {
   const child = document.createElement('div')
   child.textContent = "new"
   child.classList.add('child')
   CONTAINER.appendChild(child)
}, 2000)
```

```css
#CONTAINER .child:last-of-type {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE">
  <style>
      :host {
        background: gray;
        display: block;
      }
  </style>
  <slot>
   WC-FOO
  </slot>
</template>


<div id="CONTAINER">
    <wc-foo class="child">111</wc-foo>
    <wc-foo class="child">222</wc-foo>
    <wc-foo class="child">333</wc-foo>
    <wc-foo class="child">444</wc-foo>
    <wc-foo class="child">555</wc-foo>
</div>
```

Opened this bug report in the meantime: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1417953

Comment: `<wc-foo>` and `<div>` are not the same type. "Am I using last-of-type incorrectly?" Pretty much. "Is it a Chrome bug?" Doesn't appear to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a bug, it's working as designed (and expected). `:last-of-type` refers to the element-type, not the class-name, of an element; therefore the last `wc-foo` – regardless of its class-name – remains the `:last-of-type` even when it has an adjacent sibling with the same class-name; as the documentation says:

> ...The `:last-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the last sibling of its type.

[Citation: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#last-of-type-pseudo](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#last-of-type-pseudo).

To demonstrate, instead of a `<div>` element we can add a `<wc-foo>` element:

```js
class Component extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super().attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    });
    const template = document.getElementById("TEMPLATE");
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('wc-foo', Component);

setTimeout(() => {
  const child = document.createElement('wc-foo')
  child.textContent = "new"
  child.classList.add('child')
  CONTAINER.appendChild(child)
}, 2000)
```

```css
#CONTAINER .child:last-of-type {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<template id="TEMPLATE">
  <style>
    :host {
      background: gray;
      display: block;
    }

  </style>
  <slot>
    WC-FOO
  </slot>
</template>


<div id="CONTAINER">
  <wc-foo class="child">111</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">222</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">333</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">444</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">555</wc-foo>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/tLjmp4r1/).

References:

- [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type).

Comment: Omw that is a typo, running on two little sleep. Will delete this issue and have been spending hours trying to create a repeatible code sample, finally have. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Apologies my first code example did not demo the actual issue, here is an accurate question (took be 5 hrs to create the minimal example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530544/suspected-chrome-bug-css-last-of-type-not-updating-in-webcomponent-if-apply-c

Answer (score 0):

I would be very surprised if the Chromium team considers this a bug.

- one `<wc-foo>` is the `last-of-type`
- AND your added `<div>` is `last-of-type`

Your minimal code:

```css
#CONTAINER .child:last-of-type {
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image]

[image]

### :last-child gets you the last child

```html
<div id="CONTAINER">
  <wc-foo class="child">111</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">222</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">333</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">444</wc-foo>
  <wc-foo class="child">555</wc-foo>
  <b class="child">LAST</b>
</div>

<style>
.child:last-child {
  background:lightgreen
}
</style>
```

Comment: Apologies Danny my first code example did not demo the actual issue, here is an accurate question (took be 5 hrs to finally create the minimal example): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75530544/suspected-chrome-bug-css-last-of-type-not-updating-in-webcomponent-if-apply-c